# Get the current logged in user for UWP application takes ages to execute

Tags: c#, uwp

I have seen the following snippet of code used for retrieving the currently logged in user.

```
IReadOnlyList<User> users = await User.FindAllAsync();

var current = users.Where(p => p.AuthenticationStatus == UserAuthenticationStatus.LocallyAuthenticated &&
                                    p.Type == UserType.LocalUser).FirstOrDefault();

var data = await current.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.DomainName);
```

I have an issue with the length of time it's taking for the execution of the `await current.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.DomainName);` command. It's taking almost 10 seconds, is this expected or is there a more efficient method for getting this information back?

Answer (score 0):

So!, it turns out that the problem was down to the Privacy Settings in Windows. Because the app has been 'redeployed' the check of which app can access account info had been turned off again.

Turning this back on results in a <1 sec execution time for the command.